# Calculus of Variations problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus

I am trying to vary the following action to find the paths that extremize the action 
$$S = \int_{\gamma} \omega = \int_{t_f}^{t_i} \frac{d x^i(t)}{dt} \omega_i(x(t)) \; dt$$
where $x^i$ are are local coordinates and $\omega$ is a differential form.

So far I have
\begin{align*}
0=\delta S &= \int_{\gamma} \delta\big(\frac{d x^i(t)}{dt} \omega_i(x(t)\big) \; dt\\
&= \int_{\gamma} \Big[\frac{d \delta x^i(t)}{dt} \omega_i(x(t)) + \frac{dx^i(t)}{dt} \frac{\partial \omega_i(x(t))}{\partial x^j}\delta x^j\Big] \; dt
\end{align*}
I know the goal in variation problems is to factor out the arbitrary variation $\delta x^i$, but I am getting stuck with the integration by parts in the first term. How should I proceed in order to find the paths that extremize this action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating by parts:

$$ \intop_{\gamma} dt \left( \frac{d}{dt} \delta x^{i} \cdot \omega_{i}(x) \right) = \intop_{\gamma} dt \frac{d}{dt} \left( \delta x^{i} \omega_{i}(x) \right) - \intop_{\gamma} dt \left( \delta x^{i} \cdot \frac{d}{dt} \omega_{i}(x) \right) = $$
$$ \left. \delta x^{i} \omega_i (x) \right|_{t_1}^{t_2} - \intop_{\gamma} dt \, \delta x^j \cdot \frac{\partial \omega_j(x)}{\partial x^{i}} \cdot \dot{x}^i, $$

where the dot means differentiating w.r.t. $t$.

The first term equals to zero since $\delta x^{i}$ is fixed to vanish at the endpoints.

I trust you can derive the eq. of motion from this.

Comment: I guess I am used to dealing with actions with $x$ and $\dot{x}$ dependence, but is there a deep reason why the "Euler-Lagrange" equation for this case is of the form $\partial_i \omega_j - \partial_j \omega_i$?

Comment: @Aaron The correct form would be $(\partial_i \omega_j - \partial_j \omega_i) \dot{x}^{i} = 0$. Not sure what qualifies as a "deep reason".

Comment: @ClassicStyle I disagree. Only the pullback of $d\omega$ on $\gamma$ should vanish. This is a condition on both $\omega$ and $\gamma$. This has nothing to do with $\omega$ being closed or not.

Comment: If we say that $\gamma$ is not a closed curve then $d\omega=0$ correct? The pullback is an isomorphism of the cotangent space at each point.  I'm not entirely sure so please correct if wrong :)

Comment: @ClassicStyle Why is $d\omega$ zero?